# No password prompt for full-disk LUKS encryption

Tags: boot, kubuntu, encryption, luks, initramfs

I am running Kubuntu 20.04 on a Dell laptop. After an upgrade yesterday, my computer crashed and, on rebooting, the disk decryption password prompt is gone. Now I can't boot into the computer at all, except through a LiveUSB.

When I boot the machine, I get a message on the splash screen

```
cryptsetup: Waiting for encrypted source device UUID=...
```

If I hit F12, I get the following message:

```
[0.842138] Initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed
Volume group "vgkubuntu" not found
Cannot process volume group vgkubuntu
ALERT! encrypted source device UUID=... does not exist, can't unlock nvme0n1p3_crypt
Check cryptopts=source= bootarg: cat /proc/cmdline
or missing modules, devices cat /proc/modules; ls /dev
```

Then I am dropped into an Busybox shell, but I don't know what to do from there.

Here are the results of the commands suggested above. There may be typos, as I'm transcribing from the screen. I've only included a few relevant-looking lines, but let me know if there are other things to look for:

```
cat /proc/cmdline
BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-5.3.0-64-generic root=/dev/mapper/vgkubuntu-root ro quiet splash

cat /proc/modules
dm_crypt 45056 0 - Live 0xffffffffc036b000
...
cryptd 24576 2 ghash_clmulni_intel,crypto_simd, LIve 0xffffffffc06b7000
...
```

I can't figure out how to see all the lines returned from

```
ls /dev
```

because "less" and "more" don't work, but there are no entries for sda or sda#.

I can also boot the computer from a USB. When I do, I get the same message as above:

```
Initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed
```

but the OS opens up after that. However, after that I tried

```
fdisk -l
```

but the internal hard drive is not visible.

I would appreciate any help or suggestions for either (a) fixing the current installation to re-enable the password prompt or (b) accessing the encrypted hard drive via the USB so that I can extract some data before reinstalling.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you boot with a live cd, check if your nvme appears, and if it does, open your encrypted partition with

do you have a second disk on which the boot partition is ?

`cryptsetup open <partition> crypt`

which will give you access to the partition via `/dev/mapper/crypt`. (you can replace `crypt` by the name you want)

You can then mount the root partition (check which one it is with lsblk, but based on your logs `/dev/mapper/vgkubuntu-root`), and every other partition you see fit.

Then, you have two choices :

- extracting your data for a reinstall
- try to fix your computer

If you go for the second one, a few tips :

- you can run `blkid <blockdevice>` to view the UUID of your partition, with block device being a partition, a LVM volume...
- you can access your system via the live usb, with `chroot`, from which you may try reconfiguring your bootloader (read the docs on grub), initramfs (which is the initial system that boot, ask for your decryption password and then mount and launch the regular system you're using, conf files lives at `/etc/initramfs-tools/`, updating... But more importantly, read the logs to try to debug

Godspeed, have fun and feel free to ask for tips if you are going for the repair way !